# Not Shown Sections In Applications Window In JDeveloper

Tags: jdeveloper

When I load a project in JDeveloper I see only "Data Controls" section in the Applications window. How can I visualize the other sections - "Projects", "Application Resources" and "Recent Files"?

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: JDeveloer -> Window -> Reset Windows to Factory Setting

Answer (score 4):

In Jdeveloper Studio GoTo Window --> Reset Windows To Factory Settings

This will help to restore windows properties for application

Comment: Plagiarism was never received well.